# Is it possible to use Kubernetes autoscale on cron job pods

Tags: kubernetes, cron, scaling, hpa

Some context: I have multiple cron jobs running daily, weekly, hourly and some of which require significant processing power.
I would like to add requests and limitations to these container cron pods to try and enable vertical scaling and ensure that the assigned node will have enough capacity when being initialized. This will prevent me from having to have multiple large node available at all times and also letting me modify how many crons I can run in parallel easily.
I would like to try and avoid timed scaling since the cron jobs processing time can increase as the application grows.

**Edit - Additional Information** :
Currently I am using Digital Ocean and utilizing it's UI for cluster autoscaling. I have it working with HPA's on deployments but not crons. Adding limits to crons does not trigger cluster autoscaling to my knowledge.

I have tried to enable HPA scaling with the cron but with no success. Basically it just sits on a pending status signalling that there is insufficient CPU available and does not generate a new node.

Does HPA scaling work with cron job pods and is there a way to achieve the same type of scaling?

Answer (score 1):

HPA is used to scale more pods when pod loads are high, but this won't increase the resources on your cluster.

I think you're looking for [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) (works on AWS, GKE and Azure) and will increase cluster capacity when pods can't be scheduled.

Comment: Right now I'm currently using Digital Oceans cluster auto scaler on node pools. I'm thinking it's the same thing except it has a UI in order to configure (it automatically ads and removes nodes based on capacity). Still the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As [Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484710/dom) already mentioned *"this won't increase the resources on your cluster."* Saying more specifically, it won't create an additional **node** as **[Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) doesn't have such capability** and in fact it has nothing to do with **cluster scaling**. It's name is pretty self-exlpanatory. HPA is able only to scale `Pods` and it scales them horizontaly, in other words it can automatically increase or decrease number of replicas of your *"replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on some other application-provided metrics)"* as per [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

As to **cluster autoscaling**, as already said by [Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484710/dom), such solutions are implemented in so called **managed kubernetes solutions** such as GKE on GCP, EKS on AWS or AKS on Azure and many more. You typically don't need to do anything to enable them as they are available out of the box.

You may wonder how **HPA** and **CA** fit together. It's really well explained in [FAQ section](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work-with-cluster-autoscaler) of the **Cluster Autoscaler** project:

> #### How does Horizontal Pod Autoscaler work with Cluster Autoscaler?
>
> Horizontal Pod Autoscaler changes the deployment's or replicaset's
> number of replicas based on the current CPU load. If the load
> increases, HPA will create new replicas, for which there may or may
> not be enough space in the cluster. If there are not enough resources,
> CA will try to bring up some nodes, so that the HPA-created pods have
> a place to run. If the load decreases, HPA will stop some of the
> replicas. As a result, some nodes may become underutilized or
> completely empty, and then CA will terminate such unneeded nodes.